SQL SAS| Azure CI | The command is failing while generating xmla file from asdatabase
I am using SQL Server analysis services and having working database cube. So, now integrating Azure build to generate xmla file for each changes to the database. The key part here is the SSAS database has an assembly reference to it to achieve certain functionality.
In preparation of that,
Step1: Command line to generate asdatabase is successful.
Command used as below:
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"     "C:\Test\Test.sln" /build development /out build1.log
Step2: Command line to generate xmla is un-successful
Command used as below:
C:>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL  Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe" "C:\test\test cube.asdatabase" /d "/o:C:\Test Cube.xmla"
throws error as beloe:
Reading input files...
Error loading C:\test cube.asdatabase: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2
It would be great if someone could help us
Regards,
Sanjaya Jena
Tried checking the assembly file references, the SSAS database had assembly reference as below
